# Problem with cron job which has to run every 15 minutes but not at 15,30,45

Tags: time, cron, cron-task

So i have a cron job that runs and executes fine (hence why no path is shown) at:

```
*/15 * * * *
```

but I don't want that as it means it runs at every fifteen minutes past 0 of the hour according to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*) which gives tasks run at 15,30 and 45 minutes.

This is actually what I want:

```
1/15 * * * *
```

which according to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#1/15_*_*_*_*) should begin the 15 minutes at 1 minute past the hour and run the tasks at 16, 31 and 46 minutes.

Now the problem is when I `crontab -e` to set up the cron job of `1/15 * * * *` I get a **bad minute** error from crontab, yet as i say in my opening lines using `*/15 * * * *` returns no error from crontab and the task is executed. Why is this?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do `1,16,31,46 * * * *` to run the jobs at 1, 16, 31 and 46 minutes every hour.